# routing nginx request through index file

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, nginx, http

I would like for nginx to process:

http://dev.mydomain.com/about-us as

http://dev.mydomain.com/index.cfm/about-us

While loading the index.cfm file, Nginx must also pass along the "cgi path info" (/about-us) for server processing. I am very close but seeing some unexpected results.

Here is my current nginx config:

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    index  index.cfm index.html index.htm;
    root   /var/www;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    set $path_info $request_uri;

    try_files $uri /index.cfm$args;

    location ~* \.(cfm|cfc|cfr)$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header XAJP-PATH-INFO $path_info;
        proxy_connect_timeout 600;
        proxy_send_timeout 600;
        proxy_read_timeout 600;
        send_timeout 600;
    }

}
```

This is routing to index.cfm properly if index.cfm is not supplied in the url (such as in the "about-us" example above). However, what I find odd is that explicit requests for index.cfm, such as http://dev.mydomain.com/index.cfm actually prompt the user to download the file (like the server doesn't know how to process it).

Comment: Have you looked at Nginx Module ngx_http_rewrite_module? Should be simple enough. There are also tools which convert Apache rewrites to Nginx, Google will find them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tim, I actually wasn't aware of those tools. That said, I have just now attempted to convert the single rule of interest (and put it in place) without luck.

Comment: Post your attempt and the result.

Comment: Thank you Tim, I have posted some additional information.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you could try the following settings

```
server {
    listen       8989;
    server_name  localhost;

    index index.html;

    location / {
        return 301 $scheme://$http_host/index.cfm$uri;
    }

    location ~ /index.cfm {
        root /vhosts/default;
    }
}
```

Some basic checks

```
# curl -I http://localhost:8989/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Sat, 20 Feb 2016 01:40:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://localhost:8989/index.cfm/


# curl -I http://localhost:8989/index.cfm/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Sat, 20 Feb 2016 01:40:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 65
Last-Modified: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 23:27:42 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "56c7a4ee-41"
Accept-Ranges: bytes


# curl -I http://localhost:8989/test.html
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Sat, 20 Feb 2016 01:40:55 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://localhost:8989/index.cfm/test.html


# curl -I http://localhost:8989/index.cfm/test.html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Sat, 20 Feb 2016 01:41:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 64
Last-Modified: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 23:27:36 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "56c7a4e8-40"
Accept-Ranges: bytes


# curl -I http://localhost:8989/non_exist_file.html
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Sat, 20 Feb 2016 01:42:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://localhost:8989/index.cfm/non_exist_file.html


# curl -I http://localhost:8989/index.cfm/non_exist_file.html
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Sat, 20 Feb 2016 01:43:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 168
Connection: keep-alive
```

> I would rather not do any actual redirects though, just a "rewrite."

I would recommend to read the following topics

- https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/
- https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites

In most cases - return is more preferred.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would rather not do any actual redirects though, just a "rewrite." That said, I could be incorrectly interpreting what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with `try_files`. But you want to append the complete URL path, not the query string as you had been doing. For instance:

```
try_files $uri /index.cfm$uri;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, $uri hasn't seemed to do the trick. I switched it up and $request_uri seems to be giving me the expected value; does that sound correct to you?

Comment: That should do fine.

Comment: Thank you Michael! I'm still hung up on the fact that explicitly requesting the index file prompts a file download, any thought on that?